# Error while doind AWS Identity Centre SSO using auth0 (google as idp)

Tags: auth0, aws-iam-identity-center

I am trying to use AWS identity center (IAM IC) to enable SSO using auth0.

**Case1**: When i use IAM identity center and create permission sets,s groups and users then it works absolutely fine. I can see my AWS account on SSO url and able to access whatever permission i gave in perm set.

**Case2**: As i have already created users and policies under normal IAM thing before using this IAM identity center. I tried:

1. Creating a another IAM identity provider using metaDate file that i used in case1 from auth0
2. Created a role using above idp

bascially i followed everything that is being mentioned [here](https://auth0.com/docs/customize/integrations/aws/configure-amazon-web-services-for-sso#create-an-external-identity-provider-in-aws)

But not sure why it is not working?

I wanted to know if i can use IAM Identity Center with predefined IAM roles?